# I can't able to upload an artifact to GitHub

Tags: github, github-actions, workflow, artifacts, github-actions-artifacts

there I am facing some issues with my workflow artefacts. The Error is
-**(Error: Create Artifact Container failed: Artifact storage quota has been hit. Unable to upload any new artifacts )**

I create a zip and then upload it to artefacts does not work. and I delete my old artefacts still I'm facing this issue. I tried so many ways to upload artefacts but nothing worked for me.

I'm sharing my workflow:

```
name: Build and Deploy My App
on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    name: Creating  Build ⚒
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@main
      - name: setup Node Version To 16
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'
      - name: Installing Packages 
        run: npm install --legacy-peer-deps

      - name:  Build Project
        run: CI=false npm run build
        
      - name: zip the build folder
        run: zip release.zip ./build/** -r

      - name: Archive production artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: my-app-build
          path: release.zip

  deploy:
    name: Start The Deploying 
    needs: build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: my-app-build
          
      - name: unzip the build folder
        run: unzip my-app-build
          
      - name: All Good To Go ✔ start Sync files to hosting
        uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.3
        with:
          server: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
          username: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change version

- name:  Sync files
  uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@2.0.0
  env:
  FTP_SERVER: ${{ secrets.FTP_SERVER }}
  FTP_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.FTP_USERNAME }}
  FTP_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.FTP_PASSWORD }}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).